# Best practice for instantiating a class and loading data from database

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, mvvm

I am building a WPF application (using MVVM) which, at its most fundamental, allows users to interact with an Oracle database.

The intention is that it's a multi-user application so I need to keep synchronised with the database as much as possible.

Initial thought is to have a single application-wide instance of a "repository" class which will periodically update it's data from the database and then notify (using MvvmLight.Messaging) when updates occur.

First question; is this a sensible approach, or is there a better way of achieve this?

Second question, if the first is sensible, what's the best way of periodically firing a method (in a background thread) to update this "repository" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are creating an in-memory cache (your repository) that may be out-of-date compared to the data on the database (otherwise you would not have to "periodically update" the data in the cache). This implies that the data on the database is not static and may change over time. If your users also need to update this data then this cache won't work, as your users will be attempting to update data that is already out of date.

Caches are OK when the data is reasonably static, otherwise it is better to go to the original source of the data--the database itself.

A well designed Oracle database should be able to easily handle multiple concurrent users; it is likely that your cache (unless you really know what you are doing) won't.

Comment: Thanks for the well reasoned logic. After thinking on it some more overnight I'm leaning towards the same conclusion. An in-memory cache seems to be more complicated than it's worth. Plus, after discussion with my PL/SQL colleagues, they pointed out that this data could eventually be tens of thousands of rows so loading performance is only ever going to get worse over time as more records as added.

Answer (score 0):

A more usual approach is to push notification of changes.

SignalR is an excellent candidate for this.

The usual pattern is:

All database updates go through an app server layer.

Each client registers interest in all or a subset of data on that.

Calls via this server then result in signalr sending all "interested" clients the new data.

An alternative is:

Calls to updates go via an app server and or a mechanism such as RabbitMQ. This "splits" the signal so updates go to the database and a redis cache or in memory database.

Clients poll the cache.

The advantage of this is you reduce load on the database server.

Three are numerous variations.

For example, you might have an application used in China, America and Europe. One database server holds everything. Maybe each area is only "interested" in it's own area's data.
You could have a local app server for each area with redis cache across a couple more local machines.

Each area is then semi independent. You can implement a queuing mechanism for each which caches changes and then if your connection to China goes down for half an hour, your Chinese office can still work.

Whether any of this is worth while, only you know.

Maybe you have many users.

Maybe you need to know about changes in seconds rather than minutes

I worked on an airport system some years back.

IIRC the upper expected limit was about 3,000 concurrent users.

This just used polling.